# Do I finally get MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Given the URL `http://www.example.com/products.php`

products.php contains:

```
<?php
include ('model.inc');
$controller = new Controller;

class Controller
  function __construct()
  {
    $model = new Model;
    $this->model->model_methods();
    include ('view.inc');
  }
}
?>
```

model.inc contains:

```
<?php
class Model {
  // methods that return data 
}
?>
```

view.inc contains:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- html plus php output -->
  </body>
</html>
```

So products.php creates the controller. The controller creates the model, figures out what to do and manipulates data *only* through the model's methods, and finally turns things over to the view. The only php in the view is to output data or to loop through an array to output data.

I've been playing around with a few lightweight php frameworks that implement MVC, but so much of the magic gets done backstage that I don't know if I finally get it or not. :)

Comment: Your `View` is bad, you should pass variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is more or less MVC. The basic gist of MVC is as follows:

1. Controllers tie your models and views together and normally take care of passing model data to the view.
2. Models handle your business logic.
3. Views handle presentation and presentation related logic.

I'd definitely take time to learn PHP MVC framework such as Kohana, Lithium, Symfony, or Cake as they all provide a ton of utilities to make your life easier. They can also handle automatic routing wich makes your URLs cleaner, and helps abstract URLs from their direct connections to controllers.

- Kohana: http://kohanaframework.org/
- CodeIgniter: http://codeigniter.com
- Lithium: http://li3.me/
- Symfony: http://www.symfony-project.org/
- Cake: http://cakephp.org/

Comment: You completely left out Codeigniter http://codeigniter.com/ which out of the ones you mentioned, is the easiest to learn MVC concepts with.  It also has the best documentation as well.

Comment: Kohana is based on CodeIgniter :)

Comment: I'd personally recommend [yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) but each to there own

Comment: @letuboy: Yes, but that's like saying Ubuntu is based on Debian. While true, it's kind of misleading because the two things have developed on their own after splitting. Same with Kohana and CI, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Heh, I'll add it in to my answer but there's so many frameworks out there that you could create an enormous list. It's all about solving the customer's problem anyway, no matter the tools.

Comment: Thanks, letuboy, I've played with cake and code igniter. I kind of like CI better right now because it's simpler. I'm trying to get to the bottom of MVC here. I know there's a lot of frameworks, and they are convenient, but just to understand the mechanics of it, it should be possible to implement MVC without anything additional?

Comment: @RobertSF: If you **really** want to learn MVC, write another MVC framework! (just kidding)

Comment: @voithos: That's true! :) And that's what I'm trying to do, but just at a small scale.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this [MVC article on Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html).

If you think about what a model represents - a "model" of the data, or a subset of the data - and about what the view represents - a particular "representation" of the data - then it's easy to understand that these two entities require something to route the information between them. Hence, the controller. The flow should be `M -> C -> V`

A good test if you "understand" MVC (and thus, if your application is MVC) is **"Can I skin my application?"** If you can think of an easy way to apply different skins and styles to your data seamlessly, then you have succeeded in separating the model from the view, and your controller is effective at what it does.

Although I don't know how it's actually implemented, I'd argue that StackExchange is a great example of the MVC idea. There are multiple sites dealing with multiple topics, but they all have very similar kinds of "models" - very similar data. The presentations - the views - are free to change as they please, and the controller is there doing all the logical heavy-lifting. This may be kind of a contrived example, but I think it works conceptually, if not technically.

Comment: Thanks. Good hint about "Can I skin my application?"

Comment: @RobertSF: No prob, that was from the article I linked to. It's a good read.

Comment: That was a great article, and the comments people left were also really good.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think your Controller is responsible for too much.  Instantiating the Model and View inside the Controller "feels" wrong.  The Controller should only be responsible for getting data from Model and giving it to View.  Right now the Controller is responsible for creating the Model AND it is effectively acting as the View by including the HTML.

The important part here is that each object has, ideally, a singular responsibility.

- Model = the data holding your app  (this is really a layer instead of an object)
- View = the final output sent to the user
- Controller = give stuff to View from Model

I recommend you create some kind of "front controller" type object that handles the appropriate instantiation of objects and is the one responsible for setting up all the different pieces.

---

> Ah, ok, but how does the controller "give" the data to the view?

Well, this is really gonna be dependent upon the precise architecture your particular implementation uses.  MVC goes far beyond a simple design pattern and can be interpreted in a variety of ways.  I prefer something that looks like...

```
class Controller {

    protected $viewData = array();

    public function index() {
        $data = $this->Model->getData();
        $this->giveToView('data', $data);
    }

    public function getViewData() {
        return $this->viewData;
    }

    protected function giveToView($key, $value) {
        $this->viewData[$key] = $value;
    }

}
```

So, the Controller is still getting the data from Model but now instead of including a view file we just store the data and let a different class take care of actually rendering the output.

```
class View {

    protected $viewData;

    public function setViewData(array $data) {
        $this->viewData = $data;
    }

    public function renderViewFile($filePath) {
        // from example the variable $data is now available in this scope
        // to include the $filePath
        extract($this->viewData);
        include $filePath;
    }

}
```

Obviously this is a simplified example but the basic premise stays the same.

Comment: Ah, ok, but how does the controller "give" the data to the view? In Code Igniter you go `$this->load->view('viewfile')` so I thought to myself, you know, that's just a fancy include. :)

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the MVC is to separate your application logic (business logic, business tier, middle layer or middle tier), input (url, post data, get data) and output (UI - the html in your case).

It is an determined as architectural pattern (software architecture). It is not matter of code  but of ideologic for building applicaions.

Read here: [MVC in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

I would prefer [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) - a very static collection of functions, some named `Model` other `Controller` and there are `Views` plus a lot of utilities, allowing you to concentrate on the application logic and the layout, without loosing coding freedom in PHP (seems you use PHP). Unless you find out that it's not fitting, but that can happen with any framework.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite yet!

The `/products.php` portion is generally abstracted. The file name is matched in a `router` during execution, which matches it to a corresponding controller. In this case, you could have a `Products` controller by name, but you could match (via routing) a `things.php` request to the `Products` controller.

There's generally some more execution/initialization "magic", which calls the pertinent model/view based on the request - for example, it would take `/products.php`, change to `Product`, and look for a model, controller, and view named `Product.inc`

Comment: You can delegate routing to a higher class component, like the webserver, that's not an issue. Configure your routes in the webserver if you need to. That also separates concerns and keeps things simple.

Comment: Thanks, melee. I had actually thought of passing the rest of the data through the old `?x=a&y=b&c=z` string. I figured the controller would then figure out what to do from there, calling the appropriate model methods. Is the 'router' part itegral to MVC or is it only in web programming that you use them?

Comment: I've never worked with desktop application design, so I'm not sure if it extends beyond web applications. You'll see it in the major frameworks, though - it just takes your request and converts it to what the system needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the essential basis of the MVC pattern. The controller can be thought of as the brain which figures out what action to take. Depending on that action, it may communicate with models to get the necessary data to render the view. It then makes the necessary data available to the view and renders the HTML for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

MVC at it's most basic definition requires that you split the navigation logic, the data logic and the presentation logic into 3 parts. There is no special structure to observe as long as you have the parts split so that you can easily interchange and isolate your code.

Obviously, there are many more topics to cover if you want to be an hardcore MVC layout.

For example

1. Splitting your application into folders called controllers, views and models
2. Creating a good data layer to simplify your models as much as possible
3. Integrating a helper/widget logic so you can reuse visual components
4. Integrating a routing engine with mod_rewrite to create clean urls

Those are just a few of the items you should cover to get a real good MVC layout. But then again... MVC is a design pattern, it's a way of doing things without being something totally concrete or concise.

Comment: I see. It seems that a lot of effort goes into the routing part. I understand the URI segments point to class, method, arg 1 ..., but what was wrong with passing that in a query string? I honestly don't know. It seemed a pretty handy way.